# Variable in the curl command in bash inside quotes?

Tags: json, linux, bash, command-line

first i want to say i already readed similar topics and even thinked i found solution already, but now i get really confused because finally it appear sometimes this solution works but sometimes for unknown me reason it give fail. So, i need send to API this:

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/ppn -d 'param_one=87,a1b2c3d4&format=json&param_two=23,12,14&param_three=param_four&param_five=G&value=Password.123'
```

It have correct syntax and if i'm sending it from command line it allways works. now what i need is use *Password.123* as variable what is being taken from config.json. Here is how i realized it already with help of other similar topic by puting variable *$pass1* in double quotes *"'"$pass1"'"*.

```
#!/bin/bash
pass1=$( jq -r '.[] | .pass1' config.json; )
curl -X POST https://example.com/ppn -d 'param_one=87,a1b2c3d4&format=json&param_two=23,12,14&param_three=param_four&param_five=G&value="'"$pass1"'"'
```

but problem is, may be i'm loosing my mind already because spend too much hours at PC, but i swear it worked few times, but now it's not work at all. i guess sometimes it works, but sometimes not. mostly not and i have no idea why is that because it's being sent to public API service i have no way see any error details.

also this line with " instead of ' there not gonna work at all:

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/ppn -d "param_one=87,a1b2c3d4&format=json&param_two=23,12,14&param_three=param_four&param_five=G&value='$pass1'"
```

and not this:

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/ppn -d 'param_one=87,a1b2c3d4&format=json&param_two=23,12,14&param_three=param_four&param_five=G&value="$pass1"'
```

Or anything else i already tried. How can i workaround this? To there be sent pure command like in 1st example, by using bash script but still used variable $pass1 from config.json file?

thank you very much

Comment: Not the main problem but you might end up needing to url-encode your the password

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have literal quotes after `value=` in the URL.

Your second attempt was close except for the explicit `'` characters.

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/ppn -d "param_one=87,a1b2c3d4&format=json&param_two=23,12,14&param_three=param_four&param_five=G&value=$pass1"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This one worked! :)